# JFreeChart misses some mouse clicks

Tags: java, jfreechart

In my JfreeChart application I need to perform some actions when the user clicks the mouse on the chart. For this, I have a inner class that implements the ChartMouseListener and an instance of this class added as a chartMouseListener to the chartPanel.

The strange thing , which I cannot comprehend why , is that sometimes when I click the mouse, the application doesn't detects the click  (like somehow this event wasn't registered) .It usually happens like 2,3 times out of 10.  Has someone encountered such o problem ? Where should I check to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you implemented both the `chartMouseClicked()` and `chartMouseMoved()` handlers ? I'm wondering if you're inadvertently generating a move/drag rather than a click ?